# how do I delete duplicate relationships between two nodes with cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I run this query:

```
START n1=node(7727), n2=node(7730)
MATCH n1-[r:SKILL]->n2 RETURN r
```

it gives me a list of duplicate relationships that I have between the two nodes. what do I add to the cypher query to iterate over the relationship to keep one relationship and delete the rest?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To do this for two known nodes:

```
start n=node(1), m=node(2) match (n)-[r]->(m) 
with n,m,type(r) as t, tail(collect(r)) as coll 
foreach(x in coll | delete x)
```

To do this globally for all relationships (be warned this operation might be very expensive depending on the size of your graph):

```
start r=relationship(*) 
match (s)-[r]->(e)
with s,e,type(r) as typ, tail(collect(r)) as coll 
foreach(x in coll | delete x)
```

Comment: In recent versions of neo4j, I believe the `START` clause is unnecessary, right?  It seems to work the same without it.

Comment: I didn't understand how this worked until I realised `tail` returns all but the first element. thanks!

Comment: I was wondering where you found the "relationship" function you use? I don't see it in the documentation anywhere, only "relationships". Is it an older function?

Comment: this has been removed long time ago. These days you would just omit the first line and begin the statement with `match`.

Answer (score 7):

With Neo4J 4.x and to globally remove duplicate relationships, you'll want to use the following instead. The syntax has changed slightly and the `start` prefix mentioned in the other reply no longer works.

```
match ()-[r]->() 
match (s)-[r]->(e) 
with s,e,type(r) as typ, tail(collect(r)) as coll 
foreach(x in coll | delete x)
```

Comment: Note, why the first line?  (I think it is not needed)
match ()-[r]->()

Comment: why wouldn't `match ()-[r:RELTYPE]-() with type(r) as typ, tail(collect(r)) as coll foreach(x in coll | delete x);` work instead? Why does it delete all the relationships with that type?

Answer (score 5):

If you have trust issues about random queries that deletes data from the DB you can do what I did.

First you might want to check if the selected relationships are really duplicates. This query will set a property willBeDeleted to true, so you can check if you really want to delete those.

```
match (a)-[r]->(b) 
with a,b,type(r) as typ, tail(collect(r)) as coll 
foreach(x in coll | set x.willBeDeleted=true)
```

Now you can check which relationships will be deleted actually.

```
match(a)-[r]-(b)
where r.willBeDeleted=true
return a, b, r
```

If you think the right relationships will be deleted, then you can execute this query to delete the duplicates.

```
match (a)-[r]->(b) 
with a,b,type(r) as typ, tail(collect(r)) as coll 
foreach(x in coll | delete x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great way to find all your duplicate relationships and get some visibility into where they are happening.

```
MATCH p=(n)-[r1]->(g)<-[r2]-(n)
WHERE type(r1) = type(r2) AND r1 <> r2
RETURN type(r1) as relType, labels(n), labels(g), count(p)
```